# Collect Uni.combine failures

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

Is there a way to collect `Uni.combine().all().unis(...)` failures,  as `Uni.join().all(...).andCollectFailures()` does?

I need to call different services concurrently (with heterogeneous results) and fail all if one of them fails.

Moreover, what's the difference between `Uni.combine().all().unis(...)` and `Uni.join(...)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Uni Combine Exception**
The code should be like this,

```
return Uni.combine().all().unis(getObject1(), getObject2()).collectFailures().asTuple().flatMap(tuples -> {

            return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.ok().build());
        }).onFailure().recoverWithUni(failures -> {
            System.out.println(failures instanceof CompositeException);
            CompositeException exception = (CompositeException) failures;
            for (Throwable error : exception.getCauses()) {
                System.out.println(error.toString());
            }
            // failures.printStackTrace();
            return Uni.createFrom().item(Response.status(500).build());
        });
```

**Difference:**
Quarkus provides parallel processing through use of these two features:

*Unijoin* - Iterate through a list of objects and perform a certain
operation in parallel.
Iterate through a list of orders and perform activities on each order one by one (Multi)
OR
Iterate through a list of orders and add a method wrapper on the object in the Unijoin Builder. When the builder executes, the method wrappers are called in parallel, and its response collected in a list.

```
List<RequestDTO> reqDataList = request.getRequestData(); // Your input data
UniJoin.Builder<ResponseDTO> builder = Uni.join().builder();
for (RequestDTO requestDTO : reqDataList) {
    builder.add(process(requestDTO));
}
return builder.joinAll().andFailFast().flatMap(responseList -> {
    List<ResponseDTO> nonNullList = new ArrayList<>();
    nonNullList.addAll(responseList.stream().filter(respDTO -> {
        return respDTO != null;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return Uni.createFrom().item(nonNullList);
});
```

You can see the list of objects converted to method wrapper, 'process', which is then called in parallel when 'andFailFast' is called.

*'Uni.combine'* - Call separate methods that
returns different response in parallel.

```
List<OrderDTO> orders = new ArrayList<>();
return Uni.combine().all().unis(getCountryMasters(), 
getCurrencyMasters(updateDto)).asTuple()
    .flatMap(tuple -> {
        List<CountryDto> countries = tuple.getItem1();
        List<CurrencyDto> currencies = tuple.getItem2();
        // Get country code and currency code from each order and 
        // convert it to corresponding technical id.
        return convert(orders, countries, currencies); 
    });
```

As you see above, both methods in 'combine' returns different results and yet they are performed in parallel.